# Extend writeable stream to become transform stream?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to wrap my head around how you would do this, because you can't just inherit from `transform` and it doesn't *seem* like you can just inherit from this particular `writeable stream`.

Ideally it'd be something like:

```
const Writeable = require('Writeable');

class Transform extends Writeable {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  _transform(chunk, encoding) {

  }
}
```

But I can just tell that won't work. The particular writeable stream I'm trying to inherit from would be the [tapjs/tap-parser](https://github.com/tapjs/tap-parser). I'd ideally be able to leverage the event listeners inside of it to parse TAP output.

Comment: Why do you need to extend the parser? Can't you just instantiate a parser and just attach event listeners on it like normal?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to use the `writeable's` event listeners internally to create a `transform` stream I could pipe into and out of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about es6 syntax, but here is a traditional Transform stream that receives TAP output and outputs objects describing the various parsed parts:

```
const Transform = require('stream').Transform;
const inherits = require('util').inherits;

const Parser = require('tap-parser');

function MyTransform() {
  const self = this;
  this._parser = new Parser();

  Transform.call(this, { readableObjectMode: true });

  this._parser.on('complete', function(results) {
    self.push({ type: 'complete', results });
  }).on('assert', function(assert) {
    self.push({ type: 'assert', assert });
  }).on('comment', function(comment) {
    self.push({ type: 'comment', comment });
  }).on('plan', function(plan) {
    self.push({ type: 'plan', plan });
  }).on('version', function(version) {
    self.push({ type: 'version', version });
  }).on('bailout', function(reason) {
    self.push({ type: 'bailout', reason });
  }).on('extra', function(extra) {
    self.push({ type: 'extra', extra });
  });
}
inherits(MyTransform, Transform);

MyTransform.prototype._write = function(chunk, encoding, cb) {
  this._parser.write(chunk, cb);
};
MyTransform.prototype._flush = function(cb) {
  const self = this;
  this._parser.end(function() {
    self.push(null);
    cb();
  });
};
```

Comment: Very interesting, but how would I end processing a chunk inside one of the parser's event listeners? Seems to rely on _flush only.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, you wrote about Writable, but pasted code for Transform, not sure if  you just made a mistake, but if you did this on purpose here is an example for overnighting Transform.

Where `line` is your data, that you can play with before passing it forward.

```
let Transform = require("stream").Transform;

class awesome_class_name extends Transform
{
    constructor()
    {
        super()
    }

    _transform (line, encoding, processed) {

        //
        //  Add the data that came in, to the output stream
        //
        this.push(line);

        //
        //  We let system know that we finished processing the data.
        //
        processed();

    }
}
```